# do_action won't work in ajax callback

Tags: ajax, actions

I want to perform some actions when ajax tasks done successfully. For instance, if the item added to the cart, I want to send an email. Also may perform a few more actions.

Setting up `do_action('prefix_item_added_to_cart', $args);` doesn't recognized and so `add_action` doesn't perform a task, in my case sending email.

If I write code procedural code to send an email, that works fine but using `do_action`.

### Does not work

```
// ajax callback function
function my_ajax_callback() {

    ...
    // add item to cart
    $cart =. new Cart();
    $cart_id = $cart->add_item($params);

    // if item added successfully
    if($cart_id){
        // perform action
        do_action('prefix_item_added_to_cart', $args);
    }
    ...

}

// action callback
function send_email_to_user($args) {

    // send email notification
    wp_mail('set params for email');

}

// action
add_action('prefix_item_added_to_cart', 'send_email_to_user', $args);
```

### Works

```
function my_ajax_callback() {

    ...
    // add item to cart
    $cart =. new Cart();
    $cart_id = $cart->add_item($params);

    // if item added successfully
    if($cart_id){
        // send email notification
        wp_mail('set params for email');
    }
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: OP and me resolved the question/issue via [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115255/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-pixelngrain)** — and despite the actual problem source is not known for sure, in the actual AJAX callback used by OP, there was actually no (or maybe OP had forgotten to make the) `do_action()` call. :)

### Original Revised Answer (for reference):

If you have something like so in your actual code, i.e. the actions are registered properly:

```php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_<your action>', 'my_ajax_callback' );        // for logged-in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_<your action>', 'my_ajax_callback' ); // for all other users

add_action( 'prefix_item_added_to_cart', 'send_email_to_user' );
```

Then I don't see why would the callback function is not getting called — unless of course, if the conditional (`if ( $cart_id )`) returns `false`.

But what's that `$args` in your `add_action()` call? That parameter should be an integer, which is the callback priority.

Comment: Ah, of course, I am doing the same... Just missed adding in my sample code. My bad. Apologies

Comment: Did you add the `add_action()` code in the correct file and place?

Comment: Yes, I am `add_action()` in the correct place. I am not sure if WordPress allows or not for it. The callback function is working fine. Adding items to the cart successfully. If I use the `wp_mail` within the code as shown in the sample, it works but not the `do_action`

Comment: Are all those `add_action()` calls in the same file, can you show how you call the AJAX callback? Or try with the one in my answer - put them in the theme functions file, or in the main plugin file if you're writing a plugin.

Comment: If it's the `wp_mail()` that doesn't work, then try replacing it with `echo 'testt';` or `error_log( 'testt' );` just for testing... Do you see the `testt` on the page or in the logs - and are there any errors there?

Comment: I have a dedicated file to setup all hooks for the plugin I am writing. All hooks are working fine but this one. So I am writing code incorrect file. I will have to check it once again. The callback function is huge to post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115255/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-pixelngrain).